# How to handle large data files using Perl?

Tags: perl, bigdata

I have a file of 300GB from which I need some lines as shown below. From the below shown lines, I need only lines beginning with `>miR`.

I have written a Perl program which actually prints my desired output, but when I apply the same code for bigger file (similar lines shown below) up to 300 GB data, how to proceed with this? Is there any alternative that can be implemented in this code since the code is killed if it is run.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
$len=@ARGV;
if($len eq 0){
    print "Give file \n";
    exit;
}
$file=$ARGV[0];
open(FH,$file) || die "cant open file\n";
@lines=<FH>;
close FH;
while ($line=<FH>){
    chomp $line;
    if ($line =~ /^>miR/){
        $_=$line;
        s/>//g && s/,//g;
        print "$_\n";
        if($_=~ /(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)/){
            print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$7,"\t",$3,"\n";
        }
```

.

```
Forward:    Score: 124.000000  Q:2 to 18  R:1 to 20 Align Len (17) (64.71%) (82.35%)

   Query:    3' gaauAUUCGUUAG-AAUGGUAa 5'
                    |:: :|||| || |||| 
   Ref:      5' --ctTGGTTAATCATTCCCATt 3'

   Energy:  -10.480000 kCal/Mol

Scores for this hit:
>miR844a    AT2G33810,  124.00  -10.48  2 18    1 20    17  64.71%  82.35%


   Forward: Score: 120.000000  Q:2 to 19  R:289 to 308 Align Len (17) (64.71%) (76.47%)

   Query:    3' gaaUAUUCGUUAGAAUGGUAa 5'
                   ||::| ||  || |||| 
   Ref:      5' ttgATGGG-AAAATTTCCATt 3'

   Energy:  -9.850000 kCal/Mol

Scores for this hit:
>miR844a    AT2G33810,  120.00  -9.85   2 19    289 308 17  64.71%  76.47%


   Forward: Score: 118.000000  Q:2 to 19  R:483 to 503 Align Len (17) (64.71%) (82.35%)

   Query:    3' gaaUAUUCGUUAGAAUGGUAa 5'
                   :||:  |||| ||:||| 
   Ref:      5' gggGTAGAAAATCATATCATa 3'
```

Comment: Please format your question correctly.  Use correct grammar and capitalization. The string "i" is not a word in the English language.

Comment: The first few lines given was the code i have used and the next lines were few lines of the data of 300GB file..

Comment: I have no idea what "lines with >miR" are.

Comment: Are you parsing a FASTA file, looking for records beginning with "miR"?

Comment: @tarakaramji The source code in the question looks mangled, like linefeeds are missing - perhaps you can format it to be readable? Show us your complete best guess, rather than commented out code. (@lines=<FH> looks suspicious, for what it is worth.)

Comment: Also, `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: @kenosis: i am not taking a fasta file instead a file containing with that sign. The line which starts with ">"

Comment: @asjo: As far as ur question concern i am using @lines=<FH this to get the file each line in the loop/

Comment: OK.  Still looks like ">" can be used as a record separator, given the data you've shown above.

Answer (score 2):

We can set `local $/ = '>'` (as the record delimiter), and then use it as follows:

```
use Modern::Perl;

{
    local $/ = '>';
    while (<DATA>){
        next if !/^miR/;
        s/,//g;
        my($var0, $var1, $var2, $var6) = (split ' ', $_, 8)[0..2, 6];
        say"$var0,\t$var1,\t$var6,\t$var2";
    }
}


__DATA__
>miR844a    AT2G33810,  124.00  -10.48  2 18    1 20    17  64.71%  82.35%


   Forward: Score: 120.000000  Q:2 to 19  R:289 to 308 Align Len (17) (64.71%) (76.47%)

   Query:    3' gaaUAUUCGUUAGAAUGGUAa 5'
                   ||::| ||  || |||| 
   Ref:      5' ttgATGGG-AAAATTTCCATt 3'

   Energy:  -9.850000 kCal/Mol

Scores for this hit:
>moR844a    AT2G33810,  120.00  -9.85   2 19    289 308 17  64.71%  76.47%


   Forward: Score: 118.000000  Q:2 to 19  R:483 to 503 Align Len (17) (64.71%) (82.35%)

   Query:    3' gaaUAUUCGUUAGAAUGGUAa 5'
                   :||:  |||| ||:||| 
   Ref:      5' gggGTAGAAAATCATATCATa 3'
>miR844a    AT2G33810,  120.00  -9.85   2 19    289 308 17  64.71%  76.47%


   Forward: Score: 118.000000  Q:2 to 19  R:483 to 503 Align Len (17) (64.71%) (82.35%)

   Query:    3' gaaUAUUCGUUAGAAUGGUAa 5'
                   :||:  |||| ||:||| 
   Ref:      5' gggGTAGAAAATCATATCATa 3'
```

Output:

```
miR844a,    AT2G33810,  1,  124.00
miR844a,    AT2G33810,  289,    120.00
```

The next record (records begin with ">") is requested if the current one doesn't begin with "miR," else get rid of any commas, and then split the record to get the values you're after (from your regex).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your code splits the entire paragraph into forty or so fields. Ordinarily that wouldn't matter, but for a 300GB file I suggest `split ' ', $_, 8` instead.

Comment: @Borodin - Yes, you're quite right; excellent suggestion.  Edit made.  Thank you.

Comment: @kenosis:  is there any option of breaking the files and working on them in the code itself???? becoz the code is running slow...

Comment: @tarakaramji: you could use `grep` to extract the `>miR` lines to a separate file and then run the program on that instead. I also suggest you replace the last two lines of the loop with `print join("\t", (split ' ', $_, 8)[0,1,6,2]), "\n";`

Comment: @Borodin: The `print join` suggestion will definitely save time over my original code.  This is a good modification.  However, wouldn't `grep`--even if internally optimized--require a line-by-line file read, compared to using `$/ = '>'`?  Thank you for assisting with this solution.

Comment: @tarakaramji: Combining some of our discussion points, try the following one liner (it produces the same output shown above and may be faster):   `map { say join ",\t", ( split ' ', $_, 8 )[ 0, 1, 6, 2 ] }
  grep { /^>miR/ and s/>|,//g } <DATA>;`

Comment: @Kenosis: I was thinking of command-line grep rather than Perl grep, which would reduce the size of the file by 80% or so

Comment: @Kenosis: your one-liner will die straight away as it starts by reading the whole 300GB file into a list in memory before grepping out the unwanted lines.

Comment: @Borodin: I knew you meant a command-line grep, but failed to realize the 300GB file would first be read into a list.  Am assuming the one-liner's context forces creating the list.  Would a `for my $line (<DATA>){}` construct effectively avoid this failure?  The command-line grep makes sense as an initial pre-processing step.  Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @Kenosis: could u pls tell me if data is like this i mean each row has the data continously. so i need them in column format like miRNA target position pvalue is it possible??                               target: AT2G33810,
length: 980
miRNA : miR395e
length: 21
mfe: -9.6 kcal/mol
p-value: 1.000000
position  277